# TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier public does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting

Tags: git, azure-devops, yaml, repository, git-submodules

I have two ADO repositories named `private2` and `public2`. `private2` references `public2` as a submodule:

[image]

I also added a yaml file (vsts-cicd.yml) for build as follows:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: test
    type: git
    name: <ProjectName>/public2
    ref: master

stages:

- template: build1.yml@test
  parameters:
    repoToCheckout: test
    checkoutPath: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'

- template: build2.yml@test
  parameters:
    repoToCheckout: test
    checkoutPath: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    
- template: yaml/build3.yml
```

On running the build, I see the first two templates completed successfully. On reaching `- template: yaml/build3.yml` it fails with the following error:

[image]

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

I followed this article (https://www.timschaeps.be/post/dealing-with-error-tf401019-submodules-azure-pipelines/) to fix the issue however I don’t see this option in project settings: ‘Limit job authorization scope to referenced Azure DevOps repositories’. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

As you mention in your update, the project consuming the Repo needs to have the setting `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines` disabled in the Project Settings.

**NOTE**: Please bear in mind that this changes the build identity to collection-scoped. This could cause issues with using Auzure DevOps Artifacts. See [Scoped build identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

[image: Azure DevOps Project Pipeline Settings]

Comment: What if this is already disabled and still getting the same error?

Answer (score 5):

I dont know why its greyed out but I think you need to also disable "Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines". Worked for me.

Comment: It's greyed out when you don't have permissions to make these changes to the project. I believe that you need to be a `Project Administrator` .

Answer (score 5):

You may also need to add the proper Build Service account into the Contributors of the upstream repo.

See (https://cloudopszone.com/azure-devops-how-to-solve-remote-tf401019-the-git-repository-with-name-or-identifier/).

In other words, go to the upstream project -> Settings (gear icon) -> Permissions -> Contributors -> Members and then Add the appropriate 'XXX Build Service (yyy)'.

Comment: This solution worked for me when the other settings for limiting were already disabled and the Repository Security had no restrictions

Comment: This is the less permissive and RIGHT way of doing ! good, you read the docs! instead the precedent answers set too WIDE permissions, also the devops administrators could deny touching the "Limit job bla bla...." so prefer adding "XXX Build Service (yyy)" NOTE : you can use the Read Group instead of Contributors

Answer (score 2):

I've faced this issue recently. For me it was using wrong credentials from windows credential manager. Permission on my repository was revoked for the credentials stored. So I removed the obsolete credential and cloned again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very helpful troubleshooting guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#failing-checkout).

In my case, I needed to have do two things in order to check out a repo cross another project.

1. [Configure permissions for a project to access another project in the same project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#configure-permissions-for-a-project-to-access-another-project-in-the-same-project-collection).
2. [Configure permissions to access another repo in the same project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#example---configure-permissions-to-access-another-repo-in-the-same-project-collection).

Hope it helps!