How to I checkout with recursive submodules in Azure DevOps in the same project but different repo without disabling protections?
Different from these which are accessing a different project

Azure pipeline failed to checkout recursive submodule
Checkout Submodules in another Project in Azure DevOps Repository

Different from these which use github:

How to check out submodules on azure pipeline?
Checkout git submodule from azure pipeline
Proper Workflow for Using GitHub submodules with Azure Devops Pipelines (Adding and Checking out)

Different from this as it is for accessing another project, not the same project.

TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier abc does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting

Anyway mine is a simple enough layout I have a project with the following git repos

my-repo (has submodules my-app, my-service-a, my-service-b)
my-app
my-service-a (has submodules my-lib)
my-service-b (has submodules my-lib)
my-lib

The .gitmodules uses relative paths as required by the Submodules documentation that is in my-repo .gitmodules looks like
[submodule "my-app"]
    path = my-app
    url = ../my-app
[submodule "my-service-a"]
    path = my-service-a
    url = ../my-service-a
[submodule "my-service-b"]
    path = my-service-b
    url = ../my-service-b

I also tried full URLs with no luck.
The checkout step looks like this
steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: recursive
    persistCredentials: true

But in the end I get the following

Cloning into '/home/vsts/work/1/s/my-app'...
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier my-app does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://dev.azure.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/_git/my-app/' not found

Technically the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/79179735/242042 and TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier abc does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting would work, but it does them by bypassing the protections.

This question is similar to: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier abc does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70781149/tf401019-the-git-repository-with-name-or-identifier-public-does-not-exist-or-yo

I can clone the submodules successfully with the same layout and checkout step with yours, no matter I use the full URL or the URL like url = ../my-app

Test result:

To access the repo in the same project, please double check if the option Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines is off.

If you still cannot checkout the submodules, please check if the pipeline build service accounts account have the Read access of the repo.  Please refer the detailed step here.

I added the repositories in repositories tag shouldn't it NOT require bypassing the protection?

Hi, if you mean that you have defined the repositories in the resources session of the yaml file, you should add the - checkout: RepositoryAlias task in the pipeline. When you run the pipeline for the first time, it will need you manually permit the pipeline to access the repo. The message is :This pipeline needs permission to access  resources before this run can continue.  In this way, the submodules and the repositories can be checked out when the option Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines is on.

no I mean according to the help text it says it needs to be "referenced" in the pipeline so I wanted to reference it so I don't have to uncheck that guard.

I'll tweak the queston to make it more clear about this
